# How to extract patterns form a text files in shell bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

I have a text file that contains:

```
toto.titi.any=val1
toto.tata.any=val2
toto.tete.any=val2
```

How to extract `titi` , `tata` and `tete` from this file.

Should be some sthing like that

```
$ cat myfile.txt | sed '......'
```

and the output should be

```
titi
tata
tete
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you really need `sed`?  You could use `cut`:

```
cut -d. -f2 filename
```

Answer (score 4):

With awk you can do:

```
awk -F. '{print $2}' file
```

Answer (score 4):

awk/cut would be better choice for this problem.

here is the sed line and grep option:

```
sed -r 's/.*\.([^.]*)\..*/\1/'
grep -Po '\.\K[^.]*(?=\.)'
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk` and `cut` are best for this

you can also read the file line by line, and print out the portion needed.

```
$ IFS=.
$ while read first interested others ; do echo $interested; done < file
titi
tata
tete
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n 's/^[^.]*.\([^.]*\)..*/\1/p' myfile.txt
```

display second value between dot from line having at least 2 dot inside